# How To Solve This Problem I am New For Laravel

Tags: laravel

Warning: Unknown: Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 Fatal error: Failed opening required 'D:\next-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Console/../resources/server.php' (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line

Comment: composer install

Answer (score 0):

The problem can have several causes. One of the most common causes is an antivirus in the background. It sees the `server.php` as malicious and simply removes it. Check your antivirus and restore the removed server.php.

Answer (score 0):

Check your antivirus and add the file (server.php) as an exception.
E.g. In Avast Antivirus, go to the quarantine folder and add an exception to the file or folder you are working with.
This will help resolve the error